# Convert string "a.b.c" to $hash->{a}->{b}->{c} in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I've dynamic nested hash-refs like this:

```
my $hash = { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => 'value' } } };
```

I want to set the value of c to 'something' by allowing the user to input "a.b.c something".

Now *getting* the value could be done like this:

```
my $keys = 'a.b.c'; 
my $v='something';
my $h = $hash;
foreach my $k(split /\./, $keys) {
  $h = $h->{$k};
}
print $h; # "value"
```

But how would I *set* the value of key `c` to `$v` so that

```
print Dumper $hash;
```

would reflect the change? `$h` is not a ref at the end of the foreach loop, so changing that won't reflect the change in `$hash`. Any hints how to solve the knots in my head?

Comment: Try using the CPAN `Data::Dump` module’s `dd` function instead of the standard `Data::Dumper`’s `Dumper`. The CPAN module makes for much easier reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
my $h = $hash;
my @split_key = split /\./, $keys;
my $last_key = pop @split_key;
foreach my $k (@split_key) {
    $h = $h->{$k};
}
$h->{$last_key} = $v;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sub dive_val :lvalue {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( ($$p)->{$_} ) for @_;
   return $$p;
}

my $data;
my $key = 'a.b.c';
my $val = 'value';

dive_val($data, split /\./, $key) = $val;
```

A more powerful (and thus slightly harder to use) version of this function is provided by [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Diver).

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

my $data;
my $key = 'a.b.c';
my $val = 'value';

DiveVal($data //= {}, map \$_, split /\./, $key) = $val;
```

(daxim's usage is slightly off.)

Comment: [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31554981/589924) for how `dive_val` works.

Answer (score 3):

```
use strictures;
use Data::Diver qw(DiveVal);

my ($hash, $path, $value) = (
    { 'a' => { 'b' => { 'c' => 'value' } } },
    'a.b.c',
    'something',
);

DiveVal($hash, split /[.]/, $path) = $value;
# { a => { b => { c => 'something' } } }
```