# Create a multidimesional key of hash from array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I want to create a multidimensional `%hash` from the `@array`.

Suppose `@array` is like

```
my @array=(1,2,3,4,5);
```

I want to assign `@array` last value as final value to multidimensional `%hash` i.e

```
%hash=(
        1=>{ 
              2=>
                 {
                  3=>
                      {
                        4=>5
                       }
                  }
              }
           )
```

Which means `$hash{1}{2}{3}{4}=5;`

I want to do it in something like:

```
for my $i (0..$#array){
    #push $i as key until second last element and assign last element as value
}
```

Note : The `@array` may be of any size, Just I want to assign last element of `@array` as value to the keys of elements before the last element in `%hash`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, use `pop` to separate the value to assign from the keys. Then, you can use either of the following:

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );

my %hash;
DiveVal(\%hash, map \$_, @keys) = $val;
```

or

```
sub dive_val :lvalue {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;
   $$p
}

my %hash;
dive_val(\%hash, @keys) = $val;
```

`dive_val` works by having `$p` reference the next value to dereference and/or modify.

```
Pre-loop:            $p references $hash (the anon scalar referencing %hash)
After loop pass 0:   $p references $hash->{1}
After loop pass 1:   $p references $hash->{1}{2}
After loop pass 2:   $p references $hash->{1}{2}{3}
After loop pass 3:   $p references $hash->{1}{2}{3}{4}
```

The extra level of indirection has many benefits.

- It removes the need to treat the last key specially.
- It removes the need to create the hash before it's dereferenced.
- It removes the need for the root to be a reference to a hash. Instead, any scalar can be the root, even an undefined one.
- It makes it easy to extend `dive_val` to support mixed array/hash structures.

Comment: Sorry didn't stand this line `$p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;`. `$$p` is hashref, `$$p->$_` is value , after that I didn't get what `\()`?

Comment: `$$p` can be a hashref, but not necessarily. Within the loop, it can be undef or a hash ref. At the end of the loop, it can be anything. `\ ` gets a reference. The parens are just there to override precedence.

Comment: and why you are taking reference of reference of hash here  `my $p = \shift;`

Comment: Because that's what's needed. Look at the chart in the answer.