# Accessing a multi-dimensional hash using strings

Tags: perl, hash

I have a large multi-dimensional hash which is an import of a JSON structure.

```
my %bighash;
```

There is an element in %bighash called:

```
$bighash{'core'}{'dates'}{'year'} = 2019.
```

I have a separate string variable called core.dates.year which I would like to use to extract 2019 from %bighash.

I've written this code:

```
my @keys  = split(/\./, 'core.dates.year');
my %hash = ();
my $hash_ref = \%hash;

for my $key ( @keys ){
    $hash_ref->{$key} = {};
    $hash_ref = $hash_ref->{$key};
}
```

which when I execute:

```
say Dumper \%hash;
```

outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'core' => {
                   'dates' => {
                             'year' => {}
                           }
                 }
        };
```

All good so far. But what I now want to do is say:

```
print $bighash{\%hash};
```

Which I want to return 2019. But nothing is being returned or I'm seeing an error about "Use of uninitialized value within %bighash in concatenation (.) or string at script.pl line 1371,  line 17 (#1)...

Can someone point me into what is going on?

My project involves embedding strings in an external file which is then replaced with actual values from %bighash so it's just string interpolation.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [Hash::Flatten](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Flatten) and [Data::Diver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver)

Comment: I've included faster and simpler-to-use versions of Data::Diver's `Dive` and `DiveVal` in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no multi-dimensional hashes in Perl. Hashes are key/value pairs. Your understanding of Perl data structures is incomplete.

Re-imagine your data structure as follows

```
my %bighash = (
    core => {
        dates => {
            year => 2019,
        },
    },
);
```

There is a difference between the round parentheses `()` and the curly braces `{}`. The `%` sigil on the variable name indicates that it's a hash, that is a set of unordered key/value pairs. The round `()` are a list. Inside that list are two scalar values, i.e. a key and a value. The value is a reference to another, anonymous, hash. That's why it has curly `{}`.

Each of those levels is a separate, distinct data structure.

This rewrite of your code is similar to what [ikegami wrote in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888635/1331451), but less efficient and more verbose.

```
my @keys = split( /\./, 'core.dates.year' );

my $value = \%bighash;
for my $key (@keys) {
  $value //= $value->{$key};
}

print $value;
```

It drills down step by step into the structure and eventually gives you the final value.

Comment: So this worked for me. I also tried the dive options offered by ikegami but dive just returned the hash HASH(0x7fe01084fec8) rather than the value 2019. So I think your solution is the one I should go with. I also need to read up more about hashes and data structures.

Comment: Re "*So this worked for me.*", And the answer says, it's identical to mine. (There was a bug in `dive_val` that I fixed, though)

Comment: @MarioT. you want to read https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: @ikegami you know I'm not trying to steal your answer, right? :)

Comment: @simbabque, I have absolutely no problem with your answer. I was just disputing Mario's claim.

Comment: I'm only using the getter dive method you provided and it just returns HASH(0x7fe01084fec8). It doesn't return the value 2019. So not sure why that is - I will definitely read the two references provided by @simbabque - I can't make that dive method return anything other than HASH(0x7fe01084fec8).

Comment: I should clarify, I'm not using dive_val to set the value as I'm pulling in the larger %bighash and referencing that from dive. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: @MarioT. ikegami's `dive` sub does the same thing as my verbose code. You pass in a list. That's it. Should work exactly the same. You must have been using it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> *Can someone point me into what is going on [when I use `$bighash{\%hash}`]?*

Hash keys are strings, and the stringification of `\%hash` is something like `HASH(0x655178)`. The only element in `%bighash` has `core` —not `HASH(0x655178)`— for key, so the hash lookup returns `undef`.

---

Useful tools:

```
sub dive_val :lvalue { my $p = \shift; $p //= \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_; $$p }   # For setting
sub dive { my $r = shift; $r //= $r->{$_} for @_; $r }                       # For getting

dive_val(\%hash, split /\./, 'core.dates.year') = 2019;
say dive(\%hash, split /\./, 'core.dates.year');
```

Comment: %bighash has an entry: $bighash{'core'}{'dates'}{'year'} = 2019. which is what I'm trying to access. It's multi-dimensional.

Comment: If I print $bighash{'core'}{'dates'}{'year'} then I get 2019 as the answer. What I would like to do is say print $bighash{\%hash} to get the same answer.

Comment: That may be, but `$bighash{\%hash}` means something else. Your question was "Can someone point me into what is going on" when one does `$bighash{\%hash}`.

Comment: You might want to put some explanations on those dive subs. Especially the `lvalue` one is pretty advanced.

Comment: @simbabque, I already documented how to use in them in my answer. If instead you're interested in how it works, there's an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31554981/589924).

Answer (score 2):

[`Hash::Fold`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Fold) would seem to be helpful here. You can "flatten" your hash and then access everything with a single key.

```
use Hash::Fold 'flatten';
my $flathash = flatten(\%bighash, delimiter => '.');
print $flathash->{"core.dates.year"};
```