# How can I store hash paths to reuse them in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, path, store

Lets say I have a huge amount of elements nested in an hash (from a JSON). And I want to have getters and setters for them. For example:

```
sub set_element_x{

    my ($self, $hash_ref, $value) = @_;

    $hash_ref->{'path1'}->{'path2'}->{'x'} = $value;

    return;
}

sub get_element_x{

    my ($self, $hash_ref, $value) = @_;

    return $hash_ref->{'path1'}->{'path2'}->{'x'};
}
```

Is there a standard way of handling this paths so that you only have to change them once in case something changes in the JSON structure?

I want to add some more information because I think I did not explain my self properly.

I want to be able to store in a common place this piece of code to access a value inside the JSON:

```
->{'path1'}->{'path2'}->{'x'}
```

Which in the future may change to:

```
->{'path1_1'}->{'path2_1'}->{'path3_1'}->{'x_1'}
```

PD: If I use the piece of code provided by @stevieb 's answer I'm not able to save the structure that I want. Adding this two lines:

```
print Dumper($href) . "\n";
print to_json($href) . "\n";
```

Yields to:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'PATH1' => {
                       'PATH2' => {
                                    'a' => 'aaa',
                                    'b' => 'bbb',
                                    'y' => 'yyy',
                                    'z' => 'zzz'
                                  }
                     }
        };
{"PATH1":{"PATH2":{"a":"aaa","b":"bbb","y":"yyy","z":"zzz"}}}
```

So to sum up. I want to be able to store the hash path of a complex structure with a number of keys which is not fixed.

Comment: you could use a config file where you define your "paths". in your getter/setter/other related functions you could just refer to the config-file-keys. So whenever your JSON keys are changing, you just need to make the change in the config file instead of in all functions.

Comment: There are ways (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31554916/589924)), but is the extra run-time expense worth saving from having to change two places instead of one?

Comment: You could avoid an additional run-time expense by generating the getter and setter.

Comment: You need to talk to someone within the organization about standardizing an API. It's easy to transpose things like this for one-off, but if it's always a guessing game, the job isn't worth it imho.

Answer (score 1):

`ikegami`, in the comments was specifying about auto-generating your subs. Here's an example of that, which provides you both a single place to change your paths, as well as being rather expedient in its operation. I've also reduced your set/get methods to a single combined sub that does both operations:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use constant {
    PATH1 => '/home/steveb/PATH1',
    PATH2 => '/home/steveb/PATH2',
};

BEGIN {
    for my $elem (qw(a b y z)){
        my $sub_name = "element_$elem";

        no strict 'refs';

        *$sub_name = sub {
            my ($hash_ref, $value) = @_;
            $hash_ref->{PATH1}{PATH2}{$elem} = $value if defined $value;
            return $hash_ref->{PATH1}{PATH2}{$elem};
        }
    }
}

my $href = {};

element_a($href, 'aaa');
element_b($href, 'bbb');
element_y($href, 'yyy');
element_z($href, 'zzz');

print element_a($href) . "\n";
print element_b($href) . "\n";
print element_y($href) . "\n";
print element_z($href) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
aaa
bbb
yyy
zzz
```

What that does, is set two constant values (`PATH1` and `PATH2`) to the values you want. This happens at compile time. Next, within the `BEGIN` block, we dynamically create subroutines based on a text string ("element_") with an appended element to the end of that name. We then assign that as a typeglob within the [symbol table](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) with an anonymous subroutine with the functionality we want. This also happens at compile time. Each entry in the `for my $elem...` line will get a `element_X()` sub created.

If your paths change, you only have to change it in the `use constant` block.

Now, you appear to be using an object, so why not just dump the data within there, instead of having an arbitrary hashref being passed around? Here's an example. Note that I'm `use 5.10.0;`-ing, so that I can use the `//=` defined-or operator (as well as the `say` feature):

Package:

```
package Blah;

use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;

use constant {
    PATH1 => '/home/steveb/path1',
    PATH2 => '/home/steveb/path2',
};

BEGIN {
    for my $elem (qw(a b y z)){
        my $sub_name = "element_$elem";

        no strict 'refs';

        *$sub_name = sub {
            my ($self, $value) = @_;
            return $self->{PATH1}{PATH2}{$elem} //= $value;
        }
    }
}

sub new {return bless {}, shift};

1;
```

Script example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;

use Blah;

my $blah = Blah->new;

$blah->element_a('a');
$blah->element_b('b');
$blah->element_y('y');
$blah->element_z('z');

say $blah->element_a;
say $blah->element_b;
say $blah->element_y;
say $blah->element_z;
```

Output:

```
a
b
y
z
```

Note: Using the symbol table directly can be rather dangerous if not used with extreme care. It is trivial to overwrite things that you didn't mean to, which can cause all manner of small or large grief. That's why the `no strict 'refs'` is in use. I scoped it to the smallest block possible, and have (implicitly) ensured that there are no other `element_*` symtab (symbol table) entries in existence. `strict` catches possible violations like this, which is why we always recommend it at all times, and only disable it in as small a scope as possible, only the parts required to 'break the rules' and only when the disabling of it is absolutely required.

Comment: I just updated the question as I think i did not explain properly what I wanted to do. I appreciate you taking time to write the answer which helps me learn more for sure, but I think it does not answer the question I wanted to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if ur path has fix depth => u can use it as a array(or array ref) and use this construction, for example:

```
sub get_element_x {
  my ($hash_ref, $path) = @_;
  return $hash_ref->{$path->[0]}->{$path->[1]}->{$path->[2]};
}
```